# How to make 3 pairs of sub-lists from a Python list

Tags: python-3.x

In Python is there a way to get all 3 pairs or n pairs of a list from a list?

For example list = [1,2,3,4]
result : [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,4]]

I want to find all possible n pairs of lists from a Python list. I do not want to import any other functions like itertools.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Could you explain yourself better?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take our [tour], it only takes a minute, I promise. Then, if you have some time check our [help] for a better understanding of the site itself.

Comment: I want to find all possible n pair of lists from a list.  from my example I want to find all possible 3 pair of lists from list [1,2,3,4] then result will be [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,4]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). It comes inside Python by default (you don't need to install it throught third party modules):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 3), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 3), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 4), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 4), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 2), (4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 3), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 3), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2)]
```

This [`itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) produces all the possible permutations of a given iterable element (like a list). If `r` is not specified or is `None`, then `r` defaults to the length of the iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.

If you are looking only for `n pair` of permutations instead of all the possible permutations just delete the rest of them:

```
>>> print(list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 3))[:3])
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2)]
```

As you asked in comments you can do that without importing any module. `itertools.permutations` is just a function, which you can make by yourself:

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

But I strongly advise your importing it. If you don't want to import the whole module, just this function simply do `from itertools import permutations`.

Comment: is there other way to do it without import some function?

Comment: @eumsangwon of course, just replicate the code of that function by your own. I have posted its code in my post, but I strongly advise you importing this module. If you don't like to import the whole library just import this single function doing `from itertools import permutations`. Then you could use it as `permutations(myList)`

Comment: @eumsangwon Can I ask why you don't want to import it?